# Saddle valve on water line running to fridge won't shut off

Tags: refrigerator

I've shut off the water line to my fridge (so I can sell), but water still is coming out after turning off the saddle valve. I've even shut off the main water line, but water is still coming out of the line, but not as much. Can I stop the water without replacing valve or keeping main water line off??

Comment: You're going to have to cap off the valve.  A picture of it would help us recommend the right type of cap.  Those saddle valves are notorious for not turning off and leaking in general.

Comment: Replace the junk saddle valve with a proper quarter-turn valve. You'll get much better flow as a side benefit.

Comment: I fully agree with replacing the valve, saddle valves are junk.+

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned by a "new" user.

Answer (score 0):

If water is still coming out after turning off the valve, the valve needs to be repaired or replaced. It's possible that there is some debris or hard water deposit in the valve that is preventing it from sealing and cleaning the valve will do the trick, but a new saddle valve is so inexpensive ($15 or less) it really isn't worth any time diagnosing it; I would just replace it.

The danger is that taking the saddle valve off of the pipe to inspect or replace it might cause a leak all on its own; you may introduce a new leak between the valve and the pipe when you reassemble it.

A bigger concern in my opinion is that your main water shutoff has the same problem. If your home is going to sit vacant while on the market and you are planning to turn the water off or if you are trying to get your house in tip-top shape to sell, that's what I would hire a plumber to fix. Maybe ask him to put a new saddle valve on in the kitchen while he's there.

If you're not interested in investing money in the house or not worried about needing to have the water absolutely off after you move out, as @JPhi1618 mentioned in a comment on your question: you could do a band-aid repair by putting a cap on the end of the line to prevent damage to the flooring and let the next owner deal with it.

Comment: Saddle valves are junk and in my opinion shouldn’t be allowed. Installing a T and adding a proper valve would be the way to go.

Comment: Agreed; they are junk. The nature of this question leads me to believe plumbing in a new valve may be beyond the poster's ability or interest.

Comment: Yea, I was going to point to a 1/4" compression cap because that's most likely, but thought I would try to confirm what they had.  Saddle valves are so finicky, I wouldn't try to replace one.  Cap it or Tee with a new, proper valve.

Comment: Thx all. I've also learned saddle valves are horrible. However, I do not have the means to replace w/ the more proper valve involving welding or soldering. I think my current band-aid fix would be to replace w/ a new saddle valve - HOWEVER, even w/ my main water line shut off, it is STILL drizzling water. If I have the main off all night, should I be good to replace w/ a new saddle in the morning (until I get proper replacement)?